# Formatting a Line Space for Curly Braces in a Text File Using Java

Tags: java

Borderline coding neophyte here; I was wondering if anyone might have any tips on how to process a text document for errors, specifically concerning curly braces, and if it should identify one insert a line space to properly format it within a coding context. I've been looking all over for how to do this, but have had yet to come across a specific example.

We know to put the file's context within a String array, but that much aside we don't know how to identify specific components within said array to fix.

Comment: I would suggest that you add some code showing the work you have already done.

Comment: This is more complicated than it sounds.

Comment: Search for lexical parsing.